# Compose and andThen methods

Tags: scala

I'm following the tutorial *[Pattern matching & functional composition](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html)* on Scala `compose` and `andThen` methods. There's such an example:

```
scala> def addUmm(x: String) = x + " umm"
scala> def addAhem(x: String) = x + " ahem"

val ummThenAhem = addAhem(_).compose(addUmm(_))
```

When I try to use it I get an error:

```
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => addAhem(x$1).compose(((x$2) => addUmm(x$2))))
   val ummThenAhem = addAhem(_).compose(addUmm(_))
                             ^
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => addUmm(x$2))
   val ummThenAhem = addAhem(_).compose(addUmm(_))
                                               ^
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String
 required: Int
     val ummThenAhem = addAhem(_).compose(addUmm(_))
```

However, this works:

```
val ummThenAhem = addAhem _ compose addUmm _
```

or even

```
val ummThenAhem = addAhem _ compose addUmm
```

What's wrong with the code in the tutorial? Isn't the latter expression the same as the first one without parenthesis?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`addAhem` is a method. `compose` method is defined on functions. `addAhem _` converts `addAhem` from method to function, so `compose` can be called on it. `compose` expects a function as it's argument. You are giving it a method `addUmm` by converting `addUmm` into a function with `addUmm _` (The underscore can be left out because the compiler can automatically convert a method into a function when it knows that a function is expected anyway). So your code:

```
addAhem _ compose addUmm
```

is the same as

```
(addAhem _).compose(addUmm)
```

but not

```
addAhem(_).compose(addUmm(_))
```

PS
I didn't look at the link you provided.

Comment: For completeness's sake, the andThen example looks like:
`val ahemThenUmm = addAhem(_).andThen(addUmm (_))`
when it should look like
`val ahemThenUmm1 = (addAhem _).andThen(addUmm)`

Comment: I'm not so sure about the part written in round brackets; the compiler *does not* convert the method to function automatically, at least for Scala 2.10.2. The workaround is to declare `addAhem` and `addUmm` as functions so that `compose` or `andThen` work without the `_`.

Answer (score 50):

Well, this:

```
addUhum _
```

is an eta expansion. It converts methods into functions. On the other hand, this:

```
addUhum(_)
```

is an anonymous function. In fact, it is a partial function application, in that this parameter is not applied, and the whole thing converted into a function. It expands to:

```
x => addUhum(x)
```

The exact rules for expansion are a bit difficult to explain, but, basically, the function will "start" at the innermost expression delimiter. The exception is partial function applications, where the "x" is moved outside the function -- if `_` is used in place of a parameter.

Anyway, this is how it expands:

```
val ummThenAhem = x => addAhem(x).compose(y => addUmm(y))
```

Alas, the type inferencer doesn't know the type of x or y. If you wish, you can see exactly what it tried using the parameter `-Ytyper-debug`.

Answer (score 5):

From `compose` documentation:

> Composes two instances of Function1 in a new Function1, with this
>   function applied last.

so you should write

```
scala> val ummThenAhem = (addAhem _).compose(addUmm _)
ummThenAhem: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

to treat `addAhem` and `addUmm` as partially applied functions (i.e `function1`)

```
scala> addAhem _
res0: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

Comment: why not provide the link to the documentation?

Comment: "you do it" is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe the tutorial was written for an earlier version of Scala (probably 2.7.7 or earlier). There have been some changes in the compiler since then, namely, extensions to the type system, which now cause the type inferencing to fail on the:

```
addUhum(_).compose(addAhem(_))
```

The lifting to a function still works with that syntax if you just write:

```
addUhum(_)
```