# How to compose two functions?

Tags: scala

I have two functions, that I am trying to `compose` it:

```
  private def convert(value: String)
  : Path = decode[Path](value) match {


  private def verify(parsed: Path)
  : Path = parsed.os match {
```

I've tried as following:

```
verify compose convert _
```

The compiler complains:

```
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `verify _` or `verify(_)` instead of `verify`.
[error]     verify compose convert _
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
  def process(value: String)
  : Path =
    verify(convert(value))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not everything in scala is a function. `convert` and `verify` in your example are methods not functions.

**1) If you want to compose functions, define as functions as example below,**

functions,

```
scala> def convert: String => String = (value: String) => "converted"
convert: String => String

scala> def verify = (value: String) => if(value == "converted") "valid" else "invalid"
verify: String => String
```

**compose fns**

```
scala> def vc = verify compose convert
vc: String => String
```

**apply fn composition to functor**

```
scala> Some("my-data").map{ vc.apply }
res29: Option[String] = Some(valid)
```

**2) The another way is convert your existing methods to functions as below,**

```
scala> def vc = (verify _ compose (convert _))
vc: String => String

scala> Some("data to convert").map { vc.apply }
res36: Option[String] = Some(valid)
```

### References

https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html

[Chapter 21 - Functions/Function literals](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info)

[Function composition of methods, functions, and partially applied functions in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683362/function-composition-of-methods-functions-and-partially-applied-functions-in-s)

Comment: How to force determination of  the return type of `def convert = (value: String) => "converted"`?  Like `def convert(value: String): String = ???`

Comment: @zero_coding that becomes a method. Function has a type `A => B` which means it `takes` A and `returns B`. So, it would be `def convert: String => Path = (value: String) => ???` in your case. See updated answer

Comment: Awesome. The `signature` looks like in Haskell. Thanks a lot.